# Kernel Density Estimation, Bandwidth Tuning, Independence, and Comparison

Tags: cross-validation, hyperparameter, kernel-smoothing, nonparametric-density

like many of us here, I turn to kernel density estimation when I need a nonparametric estimate of a numerical feature's distribution, and in an attempt to assume as little as possible, I usually use cross-validation to tune the kernel's bandwidth.

Recently, however, I've been wondering whether I should tune bandwidths completely separately or independently for distributions I ultimately intend to compare. For example, if I'm comparing the past 40 years of monthly revenue between two restaurants from the same franchise or I'm comparing weekly fantasy scores between two friends, does it make more sense to tune those kernels' bandwidths independently, to use joint or at least non-independently tuned widths, or to make that decision based on some other consideration?